# Conversion to blob for many files in a directory into DB2

Tags: python, blob

I'm rather new to this. I need to convert all files (.csv and xlsx) i.e Supermarket.xlsx, sales.csv, marketing xlsx which are uploaded into a directory and convert it into a blob data into DB2, table name SB_DATA_BLOB_TEST with field names "data_column", "ingestion_date_time", "ingestion_file_name", "row_id".

I have only managed to insert 1 file, and state the timestamp, filename and row_id, but how can I apply the same function to a list of files uploaded to that directory, and apply the timestamp, list the filenames and the row_id accordingly without inserting this row_id manually as well?

The code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, run
import jaydebeapi
from project_lib import Project

constants = {
            'INPUT_DIR': '/project_data/data_asset/'
            }
file_names = {
            'Supermart': 'Supermart.xlsx'
            }
schema_name = 'ABC.'
table_prefix = 'SB_'
timestamp = pd.Timestamp.now("Asia/Singapore").strftime("%Y%m%d %H%M%S")

file = constants['INPUT_DIR'] + file_names['Supermart'] ## data
filename = constants['INPUT_DIR'] + file_names['Supermart'] ## ingestion_file_name

def convertToBinaryData(filename):
    # Convert digital data to binary format
      with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        binaryData = file.read()
      return binaryData

def insertBLOB(data, ingestion_datetime, ingestion_filename, row_id):
print("Inserting BLOB into ABC SB_Data_Blob table")  

try:
    project = Project.access()
    abc_sb_credentials = project.get_connection(name="abc_sb")

    print(abc_sb_credentials)

    abc_sb_connection = jaydebeapi.connect('com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver',
    '{}://{}:{}/{}:user={};password={};'.format('jdbc:db2',
    abc_sb_credentials['host'],
    abc_sb_credentials['port'],
    abc_sb_credentials['database'],
    abc_sb_credentials['username'],
    abc_sb_credentials['password']))
    
    
    curs = abc_sb_connection.cursor()       
    sql_insert_blob_query = """ INSERT INTO ABC.SB_DATA_BLOB_TEST
                          (data_column, ingestion_date_time, ingestion_file_name, row_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"""
    
    file = convertToBinaryData(data)

    # Convert data into tuple format
    insert_blob_tuple = (jaydebeapi.Binary(file), ingestion_datetime, ingestion_filename, row_id)
    result = curs.execute(sql_insert_blob_query, insert_blob_tuple)
    abc_sb_connection.commit()

    print("File is inserted successfully as a BLOB into SB_DATA_BLOB table", result)

except Exception as error:
    print(f"{error}")
    print("Failed inserting BLOB data into DB2 table SB_DATA_BLOB".format(error))

finally:
    ## if abc_sb_connection.is_connected():
    curs.close()
    abc_sb_connection.close()
    print("DB2 connection is closed")

insertBLOB(file, timestamp, filename, '2')
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to convert all files (.csv and xlsx) i.e Supermarket.xlsx, sales.csv, marketing xlsx which are uploaded into a directory

List all those files in your directory.
Suppose the directory is given by `constants['INPUT_DIR']` and the filenames should be filtered by extension `.xlsx` and `.csv`, then use Pythons module `glob` and its method [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob).

```
import glob

# list of filenames by given extension in given directory
csv_filenames = glob.glob(constants['INPUT_DIR'] + '*.csv')
xlsx_filenames = glob.glob(constants['INPUT_DIR'] + '*.xlsx')
all_filenames = csv_filenames + xlsx_filenames

row_id = 1  # initial row id to start inserting, will be incremented for each file
# for each of those files insert the blob, for example
for filename in all_filenames:
    path = constants['INPUT_DIR'] + filename
    ingestion_datetime = pd.Timestamp.now("Asia/Singapore").strftime("%Y%m%d %H%M%S")  # or timestamp of the file
    ingestion_filename = filename  # only the filename, no directory
    row_id += 1  # increase by one
    insertBLOB(path, ingestion_datetime, ingestion_filename, row_id):
```

Supposes your directory contains:

- `Supermart.xlsx`
- `Supermart.csv`

then the list will consist only the names like: `['Supermart.xlsx', 'Supermart.csv']`.

See also:

- [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory/48393588#48393588)